# React Router reports 404 Not Found when refresh

Tags: express, react-router, express-session

say, I have 2 pages, localhost and localhost/test, there's a link on localhost, which is to localhost/test.

localhost/test can be accessed via clicking the link, but when refreshing or input url localhost/test manually, it returns

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

My code is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, IndexLink, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import session from 'express-session';
import $ from 'jquery';

const App = React.createClass ({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Router lza.
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="test">Test</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
})

const App2 = React.createClass ({
    render() {
        return (<div>Router lza.aasss</div>);
    }
})

var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/">
            <IndexRoute component={App} />
            <Route path="/test" component={App2} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("hello"))
```

How can it be solved?

I tried to solve it by express 4, but when I import express from 'express', it reports

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Thus I tried express-session, but I can't find a complete example of how to use it. Many examples has a var called 'app', but how it's defined? Or please just tell me how to make url can be accessed when refreshing. Thank you.